# Using MSAL v0.1.3 with Aurelia for Authentication

Tags: aurelia, azure-ad-msal

I've found all kind of examples of using MSAL and even examples of using MSAL with SPA applications (generally Angular or React) but I'm struggling to get this to work with Aurelia.

I did the following to ensure that the library is actually working as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/0.1.3/js/msal.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .hidden {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="username"></div>
      <div id="token"></div>
      <button id="login" onclick="loginPopup()">Log In</button>
      <button id="logout" class="hidden">Log Out</button>
    <script>
        var authClient = new Msal.UserAgentApplication("my v2 endpoint client id",null);

       function loginPopup(){
           authClient.loginPopup(["openid","user.readbasic.all"])
           .then(token => {
               authClient.acquireTokenSilent(["user.readbasic.all"])
               .then(accessToken => {
                updateUI(token);
            },
            error => {
                authClient.acquireTokenPopup(["user.readbasic.all"])
                .then(accessToken => {
                    updateUI(token);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log("Token Error: " + error)
                })
            })

        },
        error =>{
            console.log("Login error " + error)
        })
    }

    function updateUI(token){
        var loginbutton = document.getElementById("login");
        loginbutton.className = "hidden";

        let usernamediv = document.getElementById("username");
        let tokendiv = document.getElementById("token");

        usernamediv.innerText = authClient.getUser().name;
        tokendiv.innerText = token;
    }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

That code works great.  You click the Log In button, the Login Popup is displayed, you select the user, enter your password and the popup disappears and the UI is updated appropriately with username and token.

Now I'm trying to add this into my Aurelia app as follows:

**main.js**

```
export async function configure(aurelia){
   aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

   let msClient = new Msal.UserAgentApplication('my v2 endpoint client id",null);
   aurelia.use.instance("AuthService",msClient);

   await aurelia.start();

   if(msClient.getUser()) {
        await aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app"));
   else
        await aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("login/login"));
```

**login.js**

```
export class Login {
   static inject = [Aurelia, "AuthService"]
   constructor(aurelia, auth){
        this.authService = auth
        this.app = aurelia
   }

   activate(){
        //Also tried this code in constructor
        this.authService.loginPopup(["openid","user.readbasic.all"])
         .then(token => {
             this.app.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app"))
         });
   }  
}
```

However, with this code in place, the app loads and navigates to the login page which pops up the login popup.  However, once the user enters/selects name and password, the popup screen does not go away.  The app (behind the popup) seems to reload and navigate to the app.js viewmodel but the popup remains on the screen and appears to be asking the user to enter/select username.

I've also tried using loginRedirect rather than loginPopup with a similar result in that the app is constantly redirected to the login page even after authenticating.

I'm guessing this has to do with the way MSAL is trying to respond to the app and the way Aurelia is trying to handle navigation, etc but I can't figure out where things are going awry.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a very specific issue that depends on the way MSAL behaves. The router is doing mostly what it should be, it seems. Let's connect and you can show me the behavior live and we can see if we can get it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use the `attached()` lifecycle callback

It seems like everything is working, but the popup isn't going away. It's hard to know why without seeing the code in action, but the first thing you'll want to try is moving the relevant code to the `attached()` callback, which is called once the view and view-model are bound and added to the DOM.

## Do NOT return the login promise in `activate()`

If you returned the login promise in `activate()`, activation wouldn't complete until the promise resolved. However, `app.setRoot()` is being called when the promise resolves as well, which means that you would be starting a new navigation before the first one completed. This is bad.

```
activate() {
  // THIS WOULD BREAK
  return this.authService.loginPopup(["openid","user.readbasic.all"])
    .then(token => {
      this.app.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app"))
    });
}
```

## Use the `detatched()` lifecycle callback

If that doesn't work, the next thing to do is check to see if `authService.loginPopup()` is properly logging in and resolving. If so, you can always go ahead and manually remove the popup from the DOM in the case that the library wasn't cleaning up after itself. You should do this `detatched()` lifecycle callback.

Comment: After talking with Matt, we were able to get this working by 1) using attached() rather than activate() and 2) using MSAL's loginRedirect() rather than loginPopup().